# Does there function with no bound and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|dx < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $f(x)$ with $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx < \infty$. Does there exist some function , which doesn't has a bound and has this property?

I thought no, but what about function which are near the zero and goes to infinite around zero?

Comment: Think about the graph of your function being a line  y=0, and a bunch of non intersecting triangles with suitable basis and height so that their areas are summable but the height get bigger (consequently basis get small) and bigger from one triangle to other...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is. Take $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{x}}\mathbf{1}_{(0,1]}$$ This functions has no bound, but we have:
\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x)|\,dx=\int^1_0 \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{x}}\,dx= 2<\infty
\end{align}

Comment: But $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}|$ doesn't converge.

Comment: Take a second look at the function that I have defined, please. In particular what does $\mathbf{1}_{(0,1]}$ mean?

Comment: actually I don't know. Can you tell it about ?

Comment: \begin{align}\mathbf{1}_{(0,1]}(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } & x\in (0,1]\\ 0 & \text{ if } & x\notin (0,1]\end{cases}\end{align}

Comment: @openspace Take $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ between $0$ and $1$, and zero otherwise.

Comment: @Shashi okey , I understand. That's cool thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1} n e^{-n^6(x-n)^2}$$
is clearly positive, continuous and unbounded over $\mathbb{R}^+$ (since $f(n)\geq n$), but
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x)\,dx \leq \sqrt{\pi}\,\zeta(2).$$
Similarly, $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|n| e^{-n^6(x-n)^2}$ is a positive, continuous and unbounded function over $\mathbb{R}$ whose integral exactly equals $\frac{1}{3}\pi^{5/2}$.